# How can I prevent service restarting in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service to show notification at a specific time and one `broadcastreceiver` for starting this service. When the app is started, the service is started and shows notification and shows the service in app running on the device, but sometimes in the running app service is a Restarting and the message does not display.

my service code is:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
private boolean flag=false;
public static NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    final Context context=getApplicationContext();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(CheckTime()){
                //Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReciver.class);
                //sendBroadcast(intent);
                showNotification();
            }
        }
    },0,(1000*60));

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private boolean CheckTime(){
    final Context context=getBaseContext();
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if(hour==16 && minute==11){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void showNotification() {
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent intent=new Intent(context, QuestionActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Feelinger")
            .setContentText("How are you feeling today?")
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{300, 200, 200, 200});

    android.app.NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
}
```

and BroadcastReceiver code is:

```
public class NotificationManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context,NotificationService.class));
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: post ur code , or let us know exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Write inside service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: i return START_NOT_STICKY but do not show service in runnig app and do not show notification